# Project level tsconfig.json being ignored in NestJS project

Tags: typescript, webpack, nestjs, tsconfig, ts-node

I have a NestJS project that consists of both `apps` and `libs` directories. When I run `npm run start:dev`, the `strictNullChecks` setting in the "tsconfig.json" file under `libs/core` is being ignored, resulting in an error.

Error message:

```
error TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
......
```

The project structure is as follows:

```
-- apps
---- admin
------ src
------ tsconfig.app.json
------ tsconfig.json
---- frostic
------ src
------ tsconfig.app.json
------ tsconfig.json
-- libs
---- core
------ src
------ tsconfig.json
-- nest-cli.json
-- tsconfig.json
```

tsconfig.json (root level)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file */

    /* Projects */
    "incremental": true,                                 /* Save .tsbuildinfo files to allow for incremental compilation of projects. */

    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "ES2019",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    "experimentalDecorators": true,                      /* Enable experimental support for TC39 stage 2 draft decorators. */
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,                       /* Emit design-type metadata for decorated declarations in source files. */

    /* Modules */
    "module": "commonjs",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "baseUrl": "./",                                     /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */

    /* Emit */
    "declaration": true,                                 /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
    "outDir": "dist",                                    /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    "removeComments": true,                              /* Disable emitting comments. */

    /* Interop Constraints */
    // "isolatedModules": true,                          /* Ensure that each file can be safely transpiled without relying on other imports. */
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,                /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,           /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

    /* Type Checking */
    // "strict": true,                                   /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": false,                              /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    "strictNullChecks": true,                            /* When type checking, take into account 'null' and 'undefined'. */
    "strictBindCallApply": false,                        /* Check that the arguments for 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods match the original function. */
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,                 /* Enable error reporting for fallthrough cases in switch statements. */

    /* Completeness */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

nest-cli.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
    "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
    "sourceRoot": "apps/frostic/src",
    "monorepo": true,
    "root": "apps/frostic",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "webpack": false,
        "tsConfigPath": "apps/frostic/tsconfig.json",
        "plugins": [
            {
                "name": "@nestjs/swagger/plugin",
                "options": {
                    "dtoFileNameSuffix": [
                        ".dto.ts",
                        ".model.ts"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
  },
  "projects": {
        "frostic": {
            "type": "application",
            "root": "apps/frostic",
            "entryFile": "main",
            "sourceRoot": "apps/frostic/src",
            "compilerOptions": {
                "tsConfigPath": "apps/frostic/tsconfig.json"
            }
        },
        "@frosticx/core": {
            "type": "library",
            "root": "libs/core",
            "entryFile": "index",
            "sourceRoot": "libs/core/src",
            "compilerOptions": {
                "tsConfigPath": "libs/core/tsconfig.json"
            }
        }
  }
}
```

apps/frostic/tsconfig.json

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": false,
        "outDir": "../../dist/apps/frostic",
        "paths": {
            "@frosticx/core": [
                "libs/core/src"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

libs/core/tsconfig.json

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": false,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "outDir": "../../dist/libs/core"
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

I need to enable "strictNullChecks" for the "frostic" project because I'm using a runtime type checking module (typia). However, I don't want "core" project to have "strictNullChecks" enabled, but it seems that the "libs/core/tsconfig.json" file is being ignored.